# После переноса настроек из IDEA в Android Studio пропала средняя панель

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

После переноса настроек с идеи в андротд студио перестал отображаться средний бар, как можно его вернуть?

[image: снимок экрана с пропавшей панелью]

Comment: все оказалось просто,во вкладке вью просто в отображениях включил тулбар

Comment: вероятно, стоит это оформить в качестве ответа с помощью формы внизу страницы

Comment: @mymedia рейтинг плохой, не выходит, если помочь хочешь, повысь))

Comment: странно... вроде бы репутация не влияет на возможность публикации ответов